# How to get BOOL from id

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, xcode

I'm calling valueForKey on an object. This returns an id which I tried to cast to a BOOL (because I know the value is a BOOL). But XCode gives the following warning:

> "warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size..."

So what I ended up doing was this:

```
BOOL value = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:((NSInteger)[managedObject valueForKey:@"fieldName"])] boolValue];
```

I'm thinking that there must be an easier way. Is there?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

-valueForKey: always returns an object. `id` is the objective-c type for pointer to any object.

You can examine the object in the debugger. Some useful commands:

```
po value
po [value class]
```

You'll find that the value is actually an NSNumber, so you can send it the `-boolValue` message to get the BOOL flag you are interested in.

Answer (score 28):

```
//value = (id)
NSNumber *val = value;
BOOL success = [val boolValue];
if (success) {
 //yay!
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If the value of the key is a BOOL, then the returned object will be an NSNumber. You can just ask it for its `boolValue`. You can't simply cast from an object (`id`) to a BOOL or integer or any other non-object type. The KVC machinery autoboxes scalars into the appropriate value type, so you can just ask it for the type you want. You might be interested in the [KVC docs](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html) — they explain this in more detail.

Comment: Actually, the result is in the NSNumber *class* cluster. The curious thing in this case is that it returns a bare NSNumber, not an NSCFBoolean.

Answer (score 2):

Easier? Perhaps not. More terse? Not when you asked, but in modern (since at least 2015) Obj-C, yes. If your object is a dictionary with string or number values (`NSDictionary<id, StringOrNumber>`) of any sort, you can use:

```
BOOL value = @(managedObject[@"fieldName"]).boolValue;
```

Note that, also, if you know the value you get from `@"fieldName"` is a `NSNumber`, you can just skip the conversion:

```
BOOL value = [managedObject[@"fieldName"] boolValue];
```

---

#### Why?

Thanks to some changes in the LLVM compiler:

- `NSDictionary`s can now be read and written using the familiar `dictionary[key]` syntax
- Compatible values can be turned into `NSNumber`s using the `@(value)` syntax. <sup>[more](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/#literals)</sup>
- All properties (and methods that take zero arguments and return a value) can be accessed using dot-syntax: `object.property` and `object.method`.

There's a lot of nice syntactic sugar, now. I recommend you look into it!

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

```
if let boolValue = dict["key"] as? Bool {
    // do something with boolValue
}
```